# Wake iOS app up when angle of screen changes?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10

Is there a way to hook into/run a bg task in an iOS app depending on accelerometer action? I.e. the unit elevates three feet, or goes in a certain direction

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not. You would have to run your app constantly in the background, monitoring the accelerometer constantly. And note that you really can't detect things like "raises 3 feet". The accelerometer is pretty bad at measuring changes in position because it is very subject to drift. What it detects is acceleration, so it detects jerks, bumps, and thrust. If it's moving smoothly in a car at 100 KPH it can't tell, for example.

Comment: What about the angle of the device?

Comment: Yes, you can use the accelerometer to figure out the orientation of the device. Down registers as 1 G of acceleration.

Comment: Thanks. But with iOS, as it is, there's no way to monitor this to see when it occurs in real-time?

Comment: Only if your app is actively running (foreground or background.) That drains the battery.